# Query con update inner join

Tags: sql-server, sql, join, update

No se muy bien como podría resolver esto...

En primer lugar, tengo una tabla en la que establezco la relación de entidades.

[image: Tabla Relación]

Esta tabla se llama `RelacionRecursos` y como podéis ver hay 3 campos, `RecursoAntiguo, RecursoNuevo, Empresa`

Lo que se quiere es reemplazar o sustituir los `RecursoAntiguo` por `RecursoNuevo`

Para ello, ya he sacado todas las tablas en las que se hace referencia al `RecursoAntiguo`
Un ejemplo es, la tabla `Change Log Entry` y el valor que queremos cambiar es `[New Value]`

Bien, estoy intentando hacerlo con update inner join pero no lo logro. La idea es que haga un update inner join por tabla ya que son mas 200 tablas en las que tengo que actuar y de esta manera cambie todos los `RecursoAntiguo` por los `RecursoNuevo`. También me gustaría que se pudiera filtrar por empresa.

La select que tengo es algo así

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[RelacionRecursos] relacion
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Change Log Entry] recursos ON relacion.RecursoAntiguo = recursos.[New Value] COLLATE Modern_Spanish_100_CS_AS
WHERE relacion.Empresa = 'For...'
```

¿Como podría hacer el update inner join teniendo la select?

¿Es correcta esa select con la finalidad que busco?

Comment: Por favor, modifica la pregunta e incorpora el gestor de bases de datos que utilizas (¿mysql?) y la estructura de las tablas en SQL con algún registro para las pruebas (phpMyAdmin,Exportar) y así podamos montar un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Indica exactamente el resultado quieres obtener para esos datos de ejemplo e incorpora el código de tus intentos. Aquí se explica mucho mejor [ask]. Bienvendo a [so]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la estructura de la tabla `Change log entry`? Considero que debes incluirla para poder escribir una respuesta que te funcione. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Entiendo que buscas una manera de hacer un update sobre las tablas para "dar el cambiazo" a esos valores y sustituirlos en las propias tablas, siempre que pertenezcan a determinada 'Empresa'. En principio, este código debería valerte, aunque, como dice @David en su comentario, si aportas más datos se te podrá ayudar mejor.

```
UPDATE x
 SET x.[New Value] = y.[RecursoNuevo]
 FROM [dbo].[Change Log Entry] x
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[RelacionRecursos] y
   ON x.[New Value] = y.[RecursoAntiguo]
 WHERE x.Empresa = 'For...'
```